# When I try to listen to any type of audio, the port for my audio changes really fast

Tags: sound

Can anyone help me with my audio issues?

When I try to listen to any type of audio, the port for my audio changes really fast. I'm on Ubuntu using the i3 window manager.

Here's a video of it: https://youtu.be/d9sF7vMQM88

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No need to add "unsolverd" the amount of accepted answers already tells us that